# Vertically Centering content in html

Tags: html, center, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically center a `<div>` within a `<body>`

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to design a website that is in the style of the Windows 8 Metro start screen

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always check that a question doesn't already exist before posting a similar one. Googling this shown the result straight away

Comment: @j08691 Where do I post it to? -_-

Comment: Edit your question and post it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want center block verticaly you can use this trick's

margin is a half of your size bloc.

If you use this you need size on your bloc.

html :

```
<div id="center"></div>
```

css :

```
#center{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:-200px;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ucbRs/**

or you can also use this :

css :

```
#center{
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    right:100px;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ucbRs/1/**

or you can also use a CSS3 property `align-content` like this :

```
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content:center;
}
#center{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ucbRs/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Vertically centering a `div` is actually very simple.

```
div{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

There you have it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/SLfUB/)

You might also consider [absolute centering](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/):

```
div{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Ys24x/)