# How to center image both vertically and horizontally using before and after pseudoelements

Tags: css

Today I visited a job interview and was asked the following question:

> How can you center an image of unknown height and width both vertically and horizontally without the usage of tables (e.g. `display:table-cell`)?

I was given a hint that this is possible to do using `before` and `after` pseudo elements but I failed to find a solution. Could you please guys help?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/. The ghost centring technique does that.

Comment: centered to what? A parent with defined dimensions? the viewport? the whole body?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, center to parent div

Comment: @Maximus: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/bR37X/) is demo of that exact article pointed out by Dominic Tobias. I was asked the same question by somebody a little earlier too :)

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245616/vertically-centering-content-in-html/24245798#24245798

Comment: @DominicTobias, thanks! This is probably the solution the guys wanted me to demonstrate. Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fb54U/)

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Ha, very good one! So `translateX` just moves the element up, correct? And the difference between say negative margin is that there is no need to specify length in px, correct? Here `translate(-50%)` `-50%` mean 50% of the elements height?

Comment: `translateX` moves along the X axis (left to right) `translateY` along the Y axis (top to bottom).

Comment: yeah, but I could move the element up too with negative top margin, right? However, without knowing the height of the centered box I can't specify the value for the margin, whereas with `translateX` I don't need to know the height and can say `-50%` (of the centered elements height).

Comment: Yep. Makes things much easier