# How do I center or justify buttons in a div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm creating a div with a bunch of buttons inside

```
<div>
    <button>a</button><button>b</button>
</div>
```

I want the buttons to appear justified or centered in the div. There will be several rows of buttons and they should essentially look like text but be centered/justified.

Comment: Something like that ? http://jsfiddle.net/vd7xx/ You should draw a picture to show what you need

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245616/vertically-centering-content-in-html/24245798#24245798

Answer (score 3):

if you need vertically shows this button then you use **flex-direction: column;** either use **flex-direction: row;** for Horizontally. and add this  properties in your code.

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

button{
  display:block;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  background:#d0333a;
  margin-bottom:.5rem;
  text-align:center;
  border: none;
  border-radius:6px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>a</button><button>b</button><button>c</button><button>d</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
<button style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">a</button>
<button style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">b</button>
```

Comment: margin:auto won't do anything if you don't specify a width

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is actually working.

Comment: You can check this: http://jsfiddle.net/L8u34/...

with and without using margin:auto.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property

```
text-align: center;
```

This can be used to center all inline elements, like button, text, etc...

Answer (score 0):

just use text-align:center

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <button>a</button><button>b</button>
</div>
```

Regards,
Nimesh P.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div{
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

It will do ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have button as block element  or any other block element you can do it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

and css

```
.container { width: 100%;}
.container button { display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/427Qg/)**

html

```
<div>
    <button>a</button><button>b</button><button>c</button><button>d</button><button>e</button><button>f</button><button>g</button><button>h</button>
</div>
```

css

```
div{
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align buttons horizontally and vertically centred apply the following to the parent div

html

```
<div id = "parent_div">
 <button>a</button>
 <button>b</button>
 <button>c</button>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent_div {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border:solid 1px blue;
 display:flex;/*Requires vendor prefixes*/
 justify-content:center;/*Requires vendor prefixes*/
 align-items:center;/*Requires vendor prefixes*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V4krs/)

Remove `justify-content` and `align-items` to remove vertical and horizontal alignment.

Read This:[FLEX](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)