# Make box vertically in middle

Tags: html, css

How i make div with different sizes vertically in middle of page.

For example with 100px height.

like windows 8 messages.

Thnk you.
Mohammad.

Comment: something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245616/vertically-centering-content-in-html/24245798#24245798 or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162020/vertically-align-middle-in-bootstrap-column/25162229#25162229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin:auto` in combination with `position: absolute`. Then declare all the left/top/right/bottom as zero.
It only works if you have added a `height` in your css.
It doesn't work for variable heights.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question, this is how one of the options  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sDAgG)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
</div>

.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  display:block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display:block;

}
.block:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 80px;
}
.block:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 150px;
}
.block:nth-of-type(7) {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support decrepit browsers, this is probably the easiest way. The dimensions of the element don't matter:

```
.vert_element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/agvrxnq2/)</kbd>